# Cakephp Security and Sanitize in Views

Tags: html, security, cakephp, sanitize

I have a bunch of data getting passed from controllers to views. Is there a quick way to grab all the data being passed from the controllers, like in AppController beforeRender and do a sanitize->html on that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick way: `App::import('Sanitize');` in the model and sanitize everything in beforeSave

Cake cookbook advises a different way though:

> For sanitization against XSS its generally better to save raw HTML in database without modification and sanitize at the time of output/display.

Comment: and the cookbook way is the more appropriate in most cases.